# html 5 validation is not working with google invisible recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I had a basic Html 5 form working fine earlier but after I added google invisible recaptcha to it. Html5 validation stopped working. I surfed a google lot but couldn't find a way to do that

```
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
document.getElementById("send").submit();
}
</script>

<form  id="send" action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" required name="Send" minlength="6" maxlength="16" placeholder="stackoverflow">
<button class="btn btn-primary g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="hidden" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

even if the input statements are not fulfilled it disregards that and submits the form without the error message to the user

Answer (score 5):

For recaptcha v3 you can do this. I Fixed with this.

```
<button 
                                data-sitekey="your key" 
                                data-callback='onSubmit' 
                                data-action='submit' 
                                type="submit" class="g-recaptcha btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary mt-4">Send your message</button>
                        </div>
```

update the code in provided google website with this. Basically we are manually checking form validation status before submitting it, if not showing errors.

```
<script>
        function onSubmit(token) {            
            var applicationForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");    
            if (applicationForm.checkValidity()) {
                document.getElementById("contact-form").submit();                
            } else {
              applicationForm.reportValidity();
            }
                    
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you... after trying every other suggestion on the interweb*, this one worked for me! (* - ok, I might not have tried them all... but it certainly felt like it!)

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but unfortunately we still have side-effect - validation happens after POST request was sent and token received that makes simple client-side html5 validation a bit laggy and delayed....

Answer (score 0):

Working fine here .....

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['hiddenfield'])){
echo 'submitted';
}
?>

<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
document.getElementById("send").submit();
}
</script>

<form  id="send" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield">
<input type="text" required name="Send" placeholder="stackoverflow">
<button class="btn btn-primary g-recaptcha" datasitekey="blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: are you using invisible recaptcha v2 ?? as both the code seems nearly same ??